# Сделать передвижение изображений в одну точку при скроллинге

Tags: javascript, css

Всех приветствую. Как можно реализовать такую штуку, наверное это делается на js.
Есть изображения разбросанные по одному блоку (div). При скроллинге страницы вниз, эти изображение потихоньку скапливаются в кучу и собираются в один пакетик и остаются там уже при скроллинге на следующий блок. Пример такого блока вы сможете увидеть на organic-zone .ru(не реклама) Прошу помочь, товарищи! Желательно показать на примере[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Данный код лишь для демонстрации и не готов к употреблению.

**1**. Создаем корзинку, кладем в неё все элементы задав им абсолютное позиционирование.

**2**. Расставляем элементы с помощью `transform`

---

Вот так, например, выглядит сдвиг одного элемента по оси X:

`calc(var(--tx) * (1 - var(--v, 0)))`

где `--tx` задается вручную в css файле, а `--v` обновляется скриптом.

Изначально `--v` равен нулю, но по мере приближении элемента к корзине, эта переменная будет увеличиваться до `1`.

Если убрать эти страшные спецсимволы, то уже находясь в корзинке будет что-нибудь такое: `20vw * (1 - 1)`, то есть ноль(изначальное положение).

---

**3**. Осталось только найти способ увеличивать переменную `--v`:

```
// верхушка элемента относительно всего документа(наша конечная точка)
let end = cumulativeTop(this.node)

// верхушка элемента относительно окна браузера(наша начальная точка)
let { top } = this.node.getBoundingClientRect()

// чуть-чуть сдвигаем  
end = end - innerHeight * 0.5

// чуть-чуть сдвигаем 
top += innerHeight * -0.4

// вычисляем расхождение(хуй знает как это ещё назвать)
let v = 1 / (end - top) * (scrollY - top)

// обрезаем ненужное
v = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, v))
```

```js
let rid = 0
const els = [...document.querySelectorAll('.el')].map((el, i) => {
  return {
    node: el,
    v: [0, 0],
    ease: 0.05 + Math.random() * 0.05,
    scroll() {
      let end = cumulativeTop(this.node)

      if (scrollY > end) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(rid)
        rid = null
      } else if (!rid) {
        rid = requestAnimationFrame(loop)
      }

      let { top } = this.node.getBoundingClientRect()
      end = end - innerHeight * 0.5
      top += innerHeight * -0.4
      const v = 1 / (end - top) * (scrollY - top)
      this.v[0] = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, v))
    }
  }
})

addEventListener('scroll', () => els.forEach(el => el.scroll()))

function cumulativeTop(element) {
  let top = 0
  do {
    top += element.offsetTop || 0
    element = element.offsetParent
  } while (element)

  return top
}

function loop() {
  els.forEach(el => {
    el.v[1] += (el.v[0] - el.v[1]) * el.ease
    el.node.style.setProperty('--v', el.v[1])
  })
  rid = requestAnimationFrame(loop)
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 600vh;
}

.bag-section {
  position: relative;
  height: 200vh;
  width: 100%;
   
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bag {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: calc((30vw + 30vh) / 2);
  height: calc((20vw + 20vh) / 2);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bag::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.el {
  --tx: 0vw;
  --ty: 0vh;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc((5vw + 5vh) / 2);
  height: calc((5vw + 5vh) / 2);
  background-color: lightgreen;
  transform: translate(calc(var(--tx) * (1 - var(--v, 0))), calc(var(--ty) * (1 - var(--v, 0)))) rotate(calc(360deg * var(--v, 0))) scale(calc(1 + (1 - var(--v, 0))));
}

.el-1 {
  --tx: -17vw;
  --ty: -100vh;
}

.el-2 {
  --tx: 17vw;
  --ty: -100vh;
}

.el-3 {
  --tx: 30vw;
  --ty: -150vh;
}

.el-4 {
  --tx: -30vw;
  --ty: -150vh;
}

.el-5 {
  --tx: 30vw;
  --ty: -125vh;
}

.el-6 {
  --tx: -30vw;
  --ty: -125vh;
}

.el-7 {
  --tx: -10vw;
  --ty: -80vh;
}

.el-8 {
  --tx: 10vw;
  --ty: -80vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="bag-section">
    <div class="bag">
     <div class="el el-1"></div>
     <div class="el el-2"></div>
     <div class="el el-3"></div>
     <div class="el el-4"></div>
     <div class="el el-5"></div>
     <div class="el el-6"></div>
     <div class="el el-7"></div>
     <div class="el el-8"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. Но вот теперь при натяжке на open cart, возникла такая проблема, что изображения в исходном положении не видны, пробовал всякими способами в блок сместить, но не получается, так же и с мобильной версией, там сама анимация картинок почти не видна, виден только конечный результат, не подскажете как это исправить? делаю вот тут rrabrand. kz

Comment: Я же написал, что код просто для демонстрации идеи как это можно сделать. Всё остальное что у вас там не получается / не натягивается я готов решать только за деньги

Answer (score 2):

Один из способов реализации который мне сразу приходит на ум это отслеживать событие скролла. То есть в чём идея у тебя есть n-блоков (картинок), который при скроле до определенного момента буду съезжаться в одну точку. Для каждого блока я задаю функцию изменения траектории по X и начальную позицию по Y, в идеале конечно задать функции нужно так чтобы они пересекались в одной точке, я просто подобрал нужные коэффициенты для функции чтобы показать простой пример, функция вообще необязательно должна быть линейной, можно сделать квадратную или любую другую и получить более интересные траектории по итогу. И так у нас есть функции которые задают траекторию для каждого блока и которые пересекаются в одной точке, теперь просто при событии скролла изменяем позицию каждого блока в соответствии с координатой Y и вычисляемой по функции координатой X (для absolute позиционирования это будет top и left свойства). И да, чтобы блоки не преклеивались к верху страницы задаём ускорение для координаты Y, тут тоже можно поиграться с коэффициентом для нужной скорости.

Собственно пример ниже

```js
  const blocks = [
    {
      className: 'bl1',
      yOffset: 10,
      xFunc: (y) => 0.4 * y + 30,
    },
    {
      className: 'bl2',
      yOffset: 10,
      xFunc: (y) => 0.2 * y + 170,
    },
    {
      className: 'bl3',
      yOffset: 20,
      xFunc: (y) => 0.3 * y + 90,
    },
  ];
  blocks.forEach((block) => {
    const y = block.yOffset;
    const el = document.getElementsByClassName(block.className)[0];
    el.style.top = `${y * 2}px`;
    el.style.left = `${block.xFunc(y * 2)}px`;
  });
  scrollEl.onscroll = (e) => {
    if (e.srcElement.scrollTop < 320) {
      blocks.forEach((block) => {
        const y = e.srcElement.scrollTop + block.yOffset;
        const el = document.getElementsByClassName(block.className)[0];
        el.style.top = `${y * 2}px`;
        el.style.left = `${block.xFunc(y * 2)}px`;
      });
    }
  };
```

```css
  .item {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }

  .bl1 {
    background: red;
  }

  .bl2 {
    background: blue;
  }

  .bl3 {
    background: green;
  }
  #root {
    height: 1200px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }
  #scrollEl {
    display: block;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

```html
  <div id="scrollEl">
    <div id="root">
      <div class="item bl1"></div>
      <div class="item bl2"></div>
      <div class="item bl3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Это то понятно, я же и написал потом что чисто как пример чтобы был понятен принцип